# Fail to get access lazy fetched field ( @ManyToOne ) which is part of a composite Id (using an @IdClass) when stored in L2 cache

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jcache, ehcache-3

I'm migrating from hibernate 5.6.15 to hibernate 6 (I tried with versions from 6.1.7 to 6.2.3)  and I have noticed some issues with the L2 cache when an entity has a composite Id with one of its field mapped from a many to one association.

I get an exception when I try to access the lazy fetch field from the object when it is stored in the cache.

*environment*: initially found with PostgreSQL: 14.5, reproduced with h2 2.1.214, Spring Data JPA: 3.0.6, Spring Boot: 3.0.7, ehcache 3.10.8,OpenJDK Temurin 17.0.6

### Entities

```java
@Getter
@IdClass(ProductPK.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Entity
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.ALL)
@DynamicUpdate
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product {
    public Product(String productId, Operator operator) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @ToString.Include
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
    private String productId;
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @ToString.Include
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Operator operator;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    @Setter
    private String description;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
    public static class ProductPK implements Serializable {
        private String productId;
        private String operator;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "OPERATORS")
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
@DynamicUpdate
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
public class Operator {

    public Operator(String operatorId) {
        this.operatorId = operatorId;
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @ToString.Include
    @Id
    @Column(name = "OPERATOR_ID", nullable = false)
    private String operatorId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operator", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

---

### Test 1

```java
    @Test
    void addProductAndReadFromCacheTest() {
        String string = "ID";
        String operatorID = "operatorID";
        ProductPK id = new ProductPK(string, operatorID);
        String test = "test";
        Operator operator = new Operator(operatorID);
        operatorDao.save(operator);
        Product product = new Product(string, operator);
        product.setDescription(test);
        productService.addProduct(product);

        // getProduct has @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
        // First read is made from DB
        Optional<Product> byId = productService.getProduct(id);
        assertThat(byId.orElseThrow().getOperator().getOperatorId()).isEqualTo(operatorID);
        // Second read is from cache
        Optional<Product> byId2 = productService.getProduct(id);
        assertThat(byId2.orElseThrow().getOperator().getOperatorId()).isEqualTo(operatorID);
    }
```

This test throw the following exception during `Optional<Product> byId2 = productService.getProduct(id);`

> execution: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.example.demo.local.Product was altered from com.example.demo.local.Product$ProductPK@226fd to com.example.demo.local.Product$ProductPK@44bf91

### Test 2

```java
    @Test
    void addProductAndReadFromCacheReadOnlyTest() {
        String string = "ID";
        String operatorID = "operatorID";
        ProductPK id = new ProductPK(string, operatorID);
        String test = "test";
        Operator operator = new Operator(operatorID);
        operatorDao.save(operator);
        Product product = new Product(string, operator);
        product.setDescription(test);
        productService.addProduct(product);
        // getProduct has @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW) annotation
        // First read is made from DB
        Optional<Product> byId = productService.getProduct(id);
        assertThat(byId.orElseThrow().getOperator().getOperatorId()).isEqualTo(operatorID);
        // readProduct has @Transactional(readOnly = true) annotation
        // Second read is from cache
        Optional<Product> byId2 = productService.readProduct(id);
        assertThat(byId2.orElseThrow().getOperator().getOperatorId()).isEqualTo(operatorID);
    }
```

This test raise the following exception.It seems that hibernate ignore that operator is a lazy fetched field:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.local.Operator.getOperatorId()" because the return value of "com.example.demo.local.Product.getOperator()" is null

You can find the code to reproduce this issue here : [hibernate-L2-cache-issue](https://github.com/emouty/hibernate-L2-cache-issue)

I have opened an issue on hibernate repository in case this is a bug: [HHH-16673](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16673) but I haven't got any responses for now

I would appreciate some advice on how to make this work or a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on my issue, it has been solved in version 6.2.5.Final of hibernate.